# get checkbutton value while parsing a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, tkinter, checkbox

Im parsing an hmmscan file, I created a checkbutton in order to print all domains (self.query_id) in my file . I 'm trying now to get checked values, but my code does not return anything. 
Here's the code bellow , can anyone check what is wrong with my function get_var please ?

```
    def hmmscan_parser(self):
        d={}
        #with open(self.chemin, 'r') as file:
        for qresult in SearchIO.parse(self.chemin, 'hmmscan3-domtab'):

            self.query_id = qresult.id  #sequence ID from fasta
            self.query_len = qresult.seq_len
            self.hits = qresult.hits

            self.num_hits = len(self.hits)
            if self.num_hits > 0:
                for i in range(0,self.num_hits):
                    self.hit_evalue = self.hits[i].evalue #evalue
                    self.hmm_name = self.hits[i].accession
                    self.hmm_length = self.hits[i].seq_len
                    self.chek=Checkbutton(self.frame,text=self.query_id, variable=(self.hit_evalue,self.var)).pack()
    def getvar(self):

        print(self.var.get())
```

Answer (score 1):

AS you can read at [The Tkinter Checkbutton Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm):

> > variable=
> > Associates a Tkinter variable to the button. When the button is pressed, the variable is toggled between **offvalue** and **onvalue**. Explicit changes to the variable are automatically reflected by the buttons. (variable/Variable)

Make sure `self.var` is associated with a checkbutton.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a minimal working example? Like this, it is kind of hard to find what could be wrong with your code. Make sure you do not have any typos in your code. Is there no output at all? Or is there any error message?